# why am I getting exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

This is a procedure to get the `userID` with the highest bid on an item. If there is a tie on `maxPrice` then the winner goes to whoever put in the bid first given the `itemID` and the `currentPrice` (winning bid) of the item.

```
create or replace FUNCTION GARAGESALE_getWinner(id1 int, currentPrice int) Return varchar2 RESULT_CACHE
AS
  uname varchar2(30) := 'none';
Begin
  SELECT C1.username into uname
  FROM GARAGESALE_BID B, GARAGESALE_Customer C1
  WHERE B.maxPrice >= currentPrice 
    and C1.userID = B.UserID 
    and B.itemID = id1 
    and not exists (select * 
                    from GARAGESALE_BID B2
                    where B2.bdate < B.bdate 
                      and B.maxprice = B2.maxprice 
                      and B2.itemID = B.itemID); 
  return uname;

End;
```

Here is the error message:

> Connecting to the database Team 3.
>   ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
>   ORA-06512: at "TEAM3.GARAGESALE_GETWINNER", line 7
>   ORA-06512: at line 9
>   Process exited.
>   Disconnecting from the database Team 3.

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one record in `GARAGESALE_Customer` for a given `UserID` value?

Comment: Just run the query without the `INTO` clause from SQL*Plus (or TOAD or whatever), with whatever values of `id1` and `currentPrice` are failing and see what the multiple rows are.

Comment: Just tried this and it returned the one row that I expected it to return.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the correlated sub-query will reduce the number of table scans you require:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GARAGESALE_getWinner(
  i_itemID        IN  GARAGESALE_BID.ITEMID%TYPE,
  i_currentPrice  IN  GARAGESALE_BID.MAXPRICE%TYPE
) RETURN GARAGESALE_CUSTOMER.USERNAME%TYPE RESULT_CACHE
AS
  uname GARAGESALE_CUSTOMER.USERNAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT  username
  INTO    uname
  FROM    (
    SELECT  C.username
    FROM    GARAGESALE_BID b
            INNER JOIN GARAGESALE_CUSTOMER c
            ON ( b.userID = c.userID )
    WHERE   b.maxPrice >= i_currentPrice
    AND     b.itemID   =  i_itemID
    ORDER BY
            b.maxPrice DESC,
            b.BDATE    DESC,
            b.userID   ASC
  )
  WHERE   ROWNUM = 1;

  RETURN uname;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN 'none'; -- Really? Why not NULL?
END GARAGESALE_getWinner;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

It's unclear what the tie-break is if two users have the same `maxPrice` submitted at the same time - I chose the earliest `userID` as a non-random method of breaking ties.

Answer (score -1):

This error means that you select returns more then 1 row.

To use 'into' keyword you have to be sure that you get only 1 row as result.

It can be done by adding 'rownum' to constraint.

```
SELECT C1.username into uname
  from GARAGESALE_BID B, GARAGESALE_Customer C1
  WHERE rownum < 2 and 
       B.maxPrice >= currentPrice and C1.userID = B.UserID and B.itemID = id1 and  not exists (select * 
                                                From GARAGESALE_BID B2
                                                where B2.bdate < B.bdate and B.maxprice = B2.maxprice and B2.itemID = B.itemID)
```

This will insure that your select return 1 row only.

If you need more then 1 row to return try use loop or cursor.

Comment: Downvoted because that's a band-aid.  If you expect to get 1 row and get 2, it means you have a bug.  Selecting one of them at random just to get your code "working" is not the answer.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak we dont know exactly requiments, maybe selection of random row it is ok. Anyway my answer - depends.